# Появляется только один корабль вместо ряда кораблей в pygame. Код работает без ошибок

Tags: python, pygame, спрайт

'Книга Эрик Мэтиз - изучаем python. Проект 1. Инопланетное вторжение'
'Глава 13 • Осторожно, пришельцы!'

'Проблема в том, что при запуске, видно только один корабль в верхнем левом углу. (файл приложил)'
[image: ракета]

'Должен быть ряд кораблей пришельцев, т.е. флот сдвинутый влево как тут'
[image: ряд]

'До этого момента все работает. Пули вылетают, ракета движется влево, вправо. А с этим не могу справиться. Сообщений об ошибках нет. Игра запускается.'

'alien_invasion.py'

```
import pygame

from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from alien import Alien
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Инициализирует игру и создает объект экрана.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    # Создание корабля, группы пуль и группы пришельцев.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()
    # Создание флота пришельцев.
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
    # Создание пришельца.
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    
    # Запуск основного цикла игры.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, alien, bullets)
                
run_game()
```

'settings.py'

```
class Settings():
    """Класс для хранения всех настроек игры Alien Invasion."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Инициализирует настройки игры."""
        # Параметры экрана
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        # Настройки корабля
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
        # Параметры пули
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 60, 60, 60
        self.bullets_allowed = 5
```

'ship.py'

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Инициализирует корабль и задает его начальную позицию."""
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        # Загрузка изображения корабля и получение прямоугольника.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/shipp.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        # Каждый новый корабль появляется у нижнего края экрана.
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        # Сохранение вещественной координаты центра корабля.
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
        # Флаг перемещения
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """Обновляет позицию корабля с учетом флага."""
        # Обновляется атрибут center, не rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        # Обновление атрибута rect на основании self.center.
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        """Рисует корабль в текущей позиции."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

'game_functions.py'

```
import sys
import pygame

from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Реагирует на нажатие клавиш."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()
        
def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Реагирует на отпускание клавиш."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Обрабатывает нажатия клавиш и события мыши."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, alien, bullets):
    """Обновляет изображения на экране и отображает новый экран."""
    # При каждом проходе цикла перерисовывается экран.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    # Все пули выводятся позади изображений корабля и пришельцев.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()
    alien.blitme()
    #aliens.draw(screen)
    # Отображение последнего прорисованного экрана.
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(bullets):
    """Обновляет позиции пуль и уничтожает старые пули."""
    # Обновление позиций пуль.
    bullets.update()
    # Удаление пуль, вышедших за край экрана.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

def update_aliens(aliens):
    """
    Проверяет, достиг ли флот края экрана,
    после чего обновляет позиции всех пришельцев во флоте.
    """
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
    aliens.update()

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Выпускает пулю, если максимум еще не достигнут."""
    # Создание новой пули и включение ее в группу bullets.
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    """Вычисляет количество пришельцев в ряду."""
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x

def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number):
    """Создает пришельца и размещает его в ряду."""
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    aliens.add(alien)

def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    """Создает флот пришельцев."""
    # Создание пришельца и вычисление количества пришельцев в ряду.
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    # Создание первого ряда пришельцев.
    for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
        create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number)
```

'bullet.py'

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """Класс для управления пулями, выпущенными кораблем."""
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """Создает объект пули в текущей позиции корабля."""
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        
        # Создание пули в позиции (0,0) и назначение правильной позиции.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, 
            ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
        
        # Позиция пули хранится в вещественном формате.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        
        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor
    
    def update(self):
        """Перемещает пулю вверх по экрану."""
        # Обновление позиции пули в вещественном формате.
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        # Обновление позиции прямоугольника.
        self.rect.y = self.y
        
    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Вывод пули на экран."""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

'alien.py'

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """Класс, представляющий одного пришельца."""
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Инициализирует пришельца и задает его начальную позицию."""
        super(Alien, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        
        # Загрузка изображения пришельца и назначение атрибута rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        # Каждый новый пришелец появляется в левом верхнем углу экрана.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        
        # Сохранение точной позиции пришельца.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        
    
    def blitme(self):
        """Выводит пришельца в текущем положении."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: Видимо надо проверить что у вас происходит в функции `get_number_aliens_x`

Comment: Спасибо @AlexanderChernin